# Publish translated articles through apex

Tags: apex, knowledge

I am updating translated article through apex. I need to publish them for that i tried with publish master version of article using 
 "/services/data/v25.0/knowledgeManagement/articleVersions/masterVersions/ "
REST API call. But only master article get publishing not the translated article.Can anyone tell me how to publish them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a method from documents which can be used to publish translated articles.

KbManagement.PublishingService.completeTranslation(articleVersionId);​